# identifying points in a histogram

Tags: r, histogram, interactive

in R I'm trying to interactively identify bin value in a histogram using the mouse. I think I need something equivalent to the identify() function for scatterplots. But identify() doesn't seem to work for histograms.

Answer (score 2):

Use `locator()` to find the points, then lookup which interval the value sits in, make sure it is less than the y-value for the bar, then return the count:

```
set.seed(100)
h <- hist(rnorm(1:100))

# use locator() when doing this for real, i'm going to use a saved set of points
#l <- locator()

l <- list(x = c(-2.22, -1.82, -1.26, -0.79,-0.57, -0.25, 0.18, 0.75, 
0.72, 1.26), y = c(1.46, 7.81, 3.79, 9.08, 17.11, 11.61, 15, 
17.96, 5.9, 3.37))

# for debugging purposes - the nth value of the output should match where
# the n value is shown on the histogram
text(l, labels=1:10, cex=0.7, font=2)

fi <- findInterval(l$x, h$breaks)
sel <- (l$y > 0)  & (l$y < h$counts[fi])
replace(h$counts[fi], !sel, NA)

#[1]  3 NA  9 14 NA 22 20 NA 13  7
```

[image]